# Python to Pig. Loading Binary Delimited Text

Tags: python, hadoop, apache-pig

I'm a little new to Pig/Hadoop.  I'm trying to load a server logs stored as a gzip, however the logs are stored in binary delimited form.  In Python, I would translate the file as below.  Anybody know how to accomplish this in Pig?

```
import string
import re
import gzip

unizipped = gzip.open('file.gz','rb')

for line in unzipped:
    translatedLine = line.translate(string.maketrans('\001' '\002' '\003', '|' ',' ':'))
    log = re.split('\|',translatedLine)
    print log
```

Comment: Can you mention briefly what is the logic used ? Example, how the fields are terminated and how records are terminated ? Its pretty hard for non-Python Pig Developers to help you.

Comment: So, in the first two lines of the for loop, I translate the binary delimiters.  After which, fields are separated by commas and lines are terminated by \n.

Comment: Original line looks like this [123\001key\003value\001key\003value\n].  After translation, the line would look like this [123, key:value, key:value\n].  Hope that helps.

Comment: You have to write custom loader in Java.
http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.13.0/udf.html#load-store-functions

Comment: I'll give that and a few other things I've been meaning to try.  I'll post code, if/when I find a solution - or get stuck